# How can I design a conditional SUM, to get a calendar monthly sum across various date ranges in VBA or Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset that contains consumption of units across several date ranges.
The length of the range varies: sometimes it coincides with a calendar month, other times it's all over the shop, i.e. starts on a random day of the month and ends at a random day of either the same or the next, or even 2-3 months later.

My goal is to transform the data in such a way that I have the consumption broken down (and aggregated) across calendar months instead.
For instance if I had ranges between:

1. 5 December 2020 and 14 February 2021,
2. 15 February 2021 and 9 March 2021,
3. 10 March and 30 April 2021,

it would be transformed to a dataset that would have the unit values corresponding with the full calendar months of January, February and March 2021.
For the purposes of this exercise, it can be assumed that consumption does not vary across days, i.e. each day corresponds with the same amount of consumption.

**How could this be achieved with a VBA script?**

I have explored the idea of using the worksheet function SUMIFS, but determining the date criteria (because it's a range, not a single date) seemed impossible.
I have also thought of looping through the data with several IF conditions and adding up what I need, but then I'd run the risk of not picking up certain data.

Comment: I have not written any code yet, just ran this scenario through my head and I could already see the issues that I'd hit. So I'm after seeking a conceptual advice here, rather than specific code at this stage. Would this be an inappropriate question to ask here?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to work out the number of units that would be used in the 90 days from 2021-01-01 to 2021-03-31, so the calculation would be something like number_of_units*90/(end_date-start_date+1) ? I don't think that would be too hard with a pull-down formula or a spill formula in Excel 365, not sure if you need VBA.

Comment: Not quite. I want to work out the units that are used in a calendar month, while the underlying data (each record of it) has start and end dates all over the shop. Within the same record it can be assumed that the per day unit volume is the same, however it is different in different records. Hence, if I had a record with a date range spanning across 2 months and another record that covers a subsequent period, I could work out the # units within each record with the method you propose. But then, I'd have to cobble them together to get the calendar monthly figure.